# macos cx_freeze with numpy error

Tags: macos, numpy, packaging, cx-freeze, python-3.6

mac version 10.12.5

cx_freeze version 5.0.2

python version 3.6

numpy version 1.13.0

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: input file: 
build/Cura.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.5/numpy/core/lib/libnpymath.a is not a Mach-O file build/Cura.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.5/numpy/core/lib/libnpymath.a(npy_math.o):
error: can't copy 'build/Cura.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.5/numpy/core/lib/libnpymath.a(npy_math.o):': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

I don't understand what is libnpymath.a(npy_math.o) file and why cx_freeze is trying to copy it. The files in build/Cura.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.5/numpy/core/lib/ directory are

```
libnpymath.a
npy-pkg-config
```

Same question in cx_freeze mailing list, but no answer unfortunately. 
https://sourceforge.net/p/cx-freeze/mailman/message/35571322/